# Folder set up in linux for netbeans

Tags: linux, path, netbeans

Kind of new to linux.  Learning PHP, I downloaded NetBeans IDE but having problems getting a new project to show up on left hand side with other projects.  It keeps putting them in the source file of the sample project that is there when you download the program.

We are using a html file which I think is where all my projects are going to end up.
the path to the html file is var/www/html.
When I create a new project, I change the Sources folder to match that example:
/var/www/PhpProject1   But it tells me the sources folder is not writable.  (must be doing something wrong)

When I look at Places - home, I see along with my desktop and download folders, a NetBeansProjects folder which I do not remember putting there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have read/write/execute privileges on that path. [This post on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19898/whats-the-simplest-way-to-edit-and-add-files-to-var-www) seems to describe the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and here is how i solved it...!

```
sudo chown -R <your username>:<apache group name> directory
```

in my case that command became

```
sudo chown -R joe:root /opt/lampp
```